# How to use CountVectorizer before building a Bayes classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes, countvectorizer

After the preprocessing of raw data, the Spam data from Kaggle. I had already removed all the stop words and useless words. Now it is requested to use CountVectorizer to quantify the cleaned words. But I don't know how to do it and what is the concept behind it.

As I just learned the count function to calculate the frequency of words appearance. But I have no idea about CountVectorizer. I checked online, but it seemed there were limited resources.

```
spam['filtered'].head()

0    [Go, jurong, point, crazy.., avail, bugi, n, g...
1               [Ok, lar, ..., joke, wif, u, oni, ...]
2    [free, entri, 2, wkli, comp, win, FA, cup, fin...
3    [U, dun, say, earli, hor, ..., U, c, alreadi, ...
4    [nah, n't, think, goe, usf, live, around, though]
Name: filtered, dtype: object

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
```

So how to do next? Also, how to conduct Naive Bayes classifier after this?

Comment: These questions are *way* too broad. For starters, `pandas` really isn't the best tool or an NLP pipeline. `CountVectorizer` from sklearn will already tokenize and do stopword removal for you, and you can hook into those functions with your own custom implementaiton of either stopword removal or tokenization. I am voting to close this question as too broad, but take a look at the sklearn docs/tutorials, like this one: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction the documentation for sklearn is pretty good

Comment: Oh, thank you! I am a starter. Sorry...

Comment: No need to apologize, it's just StackOverflow is designed for more specific questions than this. Seriously, read through that tutorial. Sklearn tutorials/documentation are quite good.